# PHP. Конкатенация константы со строкой в определении константы

Tags: php, php5

Перепробовал много способов определить константу на основе другой. Ничего не выходит. Гугл и мануалы тоже особо не помогли.

```
class Config {
    const PROJ_ROOT = "/srv/www/htdocs/inet_shop/admin";
    const IMAGES_DIR = self::PROJ_ROOT . "/images"; // тут ошибка
    // ...
}
```

---

Запускаю через консоль тесты и выдаёт:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in /srv/www/htdocs/inet_shop/admin/config.php on line 5
```

Почему?

Comment: Версия php какая? Ибо "Поддержка константных выражений была добавлена в PHP 5.6.0.", в __мануале__ написано, кстати.

Comment: @u_mulder 5.5.14

Comment: Смотрите сообщение выше.

Comment: @u_mulder Да уже понятно